# GoogleMaps Places swift 2, places searchbox

Tags: google-maps, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to create a autocomplete google places search box, and i was searching at googlemaps documentation this code below, but xcode mark me an error at the line

```
     let place = placeLicklihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
```

Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'place'

```
           var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient?

    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func getCurrentPlace(sender: AnyObject) {
        placesClient?.currentPlaceWithCallback({ (placeLikelihoodList: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            self.nameLabel.text = "No current place"
            self.addressLabel.text = ""

            if let placeLicklihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
                let place = placeLicklihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
                if let place = place
                {
                    self.nameLabel.text = place.name
                    self.addressLabel.text = "\n".join(place.formattedAddress.componentsSeparatedByString(", "))
                }
            }
        })
    }



          override func viewDidLoad() {
             placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()

    }
```

I been searching for tutorial for the autocomplete google place searchbox but not of them work

Comment: I tried your code in XCode 7, and there is no issue, my git snippet: https://gist.github.com/ziyang0621/b016214c5e689b88299f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
placesClient?.currentPlaceWithCallback({
        (placeLikelihoodList: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        if let placeLicklihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {

            let  place = placeLicklihoodList.likelihoods.first as! GMSPlaceLikelihood
            if let place : GMSPlaceLikelihood = place {
                print(place.place.formattedAddress)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Please provide explanation along with the code sample.

Comment: Hello, the output type of placeLicklihoodList.likelihoods.first is AnyObject (it's the first value of AnyObject table ). So you just need to convert it to Place type using GMSPlaceLikeLihood. And now you can acces all attributes of the type Place. Excuse my english.